Time evolution using non-Hermitian (not a PT symmetric) Hamiltonian
I am currently  dealing with non-Hermitian hamiltonian and dynamics using it. In general the diagonalizable non-Hermitian matrix might have complex eigenvalues and the eigenvectors may not be orthogonal with each other. Now I can see that in literature, the evolution operator is still considered to be $U=e^{-iHt}$. My first question is that since eigenvalues of $H$ is complex, how to eigen-decompose $U$ in terms of its eigenvalues and eigenvectors? If it is possible to do so, then the factors $e^{-iE_jt}$ may blow up (for negative imaginary part of eigenvalues) at long time. How to deal with these and construct evolution operator in proper way?
